# Hibernate core Jakarta with spring

Tags: spring, hibernate

Can I use hibernate core Jakarta 5.6.15 with spring 5 or spring 6 is must.
When I am using it with spring 6 get errors in bean creation.

```
shouldStoreAndRetrieve()  Time elapsed: 0.012 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@533f878e testClass = net.sys.server.dao.QueueStatusLogDAOIT, locations = [], classes = [net.sys.server.spring.config.TestConfig], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties = [], contextCustomizers = [], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.test.context.web.WebDelegatingSmartContextLoader, parent = null]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'testConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'configDAO': Error creating bean with name 'configDAO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory': Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in net.sys.server.spring.config.TestConfig: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ClassLoaderDelegate
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'configDAO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory': Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in net.sys.server.spring.config.TestConfig: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ClassLoaderDelegate
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in net.sys.server.spring.config.TestConfig: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ClassLoaderDelegate
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ClassLoaderDelegate
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ClassLoaderDelegate
```

```
package net.sys.server.dao;

import net.sys.server.model.Config;

public interface ConfigDAO extends DAO<Config, Long> {

    Config findByConfigKey(final String configKey);
}


package net.sys.server.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Lob;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

import java.time.Instant;

@Entity
@Table(name = "config")
public class Config {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "config_key")
    private String configKey;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "default_config_json")
    private String defaultConfigJson;

    @Column(name = "timestamp")
    private Instant timestamp;
```

'''

```
    public Config() {}

    public Config(String configKey, String defaultConfigJson, Instant timestamp) {
        this.configKey = configKey;
        this.defaultConfigJson = defaultConfigJson;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public String getConfigKey() {
        return configKey;
    }

    public String getDefaultConfigJson() {
        return defaultConfigJson;
    }

    public Instant getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }
}
```

''''

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(
        basePackages = "net.sys",
        excludeFilters = {
            @ComponentScan.Filter(
                    type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,
                    value = {DispatcherConfig.class, WebAppInitializer.class, DBConfig.class})
        })
@PropertySource({"classpath:gis.properties"})
@ActiveProfiles("integration-test")
public class TestConfig {

    private static final String UTF_8 = "UTF-8";
    private static final Instant CURRENT_TIME = now();
    private static final String DEFAULT_CONFIG_JSON_PATH = "config/defaultConfig.json";
    private static String defaultConfigurationJson = "";

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private ConfigDAO configDAO;

    @PostConstruct
    void init() throws IOException {
        defaultConfigDao();
    }

    @Bean
    FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging() {
        return mock(FirebaseMessaging.class);
    }

    @Bean
    DataSource dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).build();
    }

    @Bean
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        localSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        localSessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("net.sys");
        localSessionFactoryBean.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("hibernate.cfg.xml"));

        return localSessionFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    @RequestScope
    BookingAuthentication bookingAuthentication() {
        return new BookingAuthentication();
    }

    @Bean
    VelocityEngine velocityEngine() throws VelocityException, IOException {
        final VelocityEngineFactoryBean factory = new VelocityEngineFactoryBean();
        factory.setVelocityProperties(velocityProperties());

        // Space after the comma causes problem.  So, don't give a space after comma
        factory.setResourceLoaderPath("classpath:/views/,"
                + env.getProperty(ENV_SCRIPT_CORE_LOCATION)
                + ","
                + env.getProperty(ENV_SCRIPT_CUSTOM_LOCATION));
        return factory.createVelocityEngine();
    }

   

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers", "true");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("show_sql", "false");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("format_sql", "true");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("use_sql_comments", "false");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");

        return hibernateProperties;
    }

    private Properties velocityProperties() throws IOException {
        Properties velocityProperties = new Properties();
        velocityProperties.setProperty("input.encoding", UTF_8);
        velocityProperties.setProperty("output.encoding", UTF_8);

        return velocityProperties;
    }

    private void defaultConfigDao() throws IOException {
        defaultConfigurationJson = getDefaultJsonConfigFile(DEFAULT_CONFIG_JSON_PATH);
        configDAO.saveOrUpdate(new Config(CONFIG_KEY, defaultConfigurationJson, CURRENT_TIME));
    }

    private String getDefaultJsonConfigFile(final String name) throws IOException {
        return Files.toString(getFile("classpath:" + name), Charset.defaultCharset());
    }
}
```

I am migrated to hibernate 6 with spring 6.. Previous working fine with same code. I am migrated to hibernate 6 with spring 6.. Previous working fine with same code.

```
    <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-session-hazelcast</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-session.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>${javax.servlet-api.version}</version>
    <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>${jakarta.servlet-api.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
    <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
    <version>${velocity.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
            <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.transaction-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.25.0-GA</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>${commons-dbcp.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.21.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
    <version>${mysql-connection.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>${gson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>${logback.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>${logback.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
    <version>${glassfish-javax-json.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.logback-extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-ext-loggly</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson-core.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson-core.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson-core.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson-core.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson-core.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson-core.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
    <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
    <version>${auth0.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.shield-solutions</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-velocity-adapter</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-velocity-adapter.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
    <artifactId>hazelcast-spring</artifactId>
    <version>${hazelcast.version}</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Hazelcast is used at runtime by Spring -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
    <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
    <version>${hazelcast.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>${springfox.swagger2.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>${springfox.swagger2.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>${guava.version}</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Test Dependencies -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava-testlib</artifactId>
    <version>${guava.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>${mockito.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>${h2.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
    <version>${jayway-json-path.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.trajano.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-testing</artifactId>
    <version>${trajano-commons-testing.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Show the error that you have and then we will be able to help you.

Comment: edited. I am using hibernate 6 than this error occur

Comment: As a reason of this exception could be miss configuration in `configDao`.

Comment: updated with code please help

Comment: Can you try updating ` hibernate core Jakarta ` to `6.x` version ?

Comment: yes i am using hibernate 6 .

Comment: when i am using hibernate-core-jakarta i am getting error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@21d54321 testClass = net..dao.hibernate.Abc, locations = [], classes = [.config.TestConfig], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles ..
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testConfig': Invocation of init method failed
No CurrentSessionContext configured!

Comment: can you provide also `pom.xml` ?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ClassLoaderDelegate in HIBERNATE 6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257006/discussion-between-syeda-maira-saad-and-andrei-lisa).